# Android kitkat (Api 19) styling

Tags: android, android-studio, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I'm trying to change the color of the DatePickerDialog (See image below) in API 19 (Android 4.4 Kitkat).

[image: Picture of the DatePickerDialog]

I'm creating the DatePickerDialog when clicking on an EditText box, so I don't have an XML file, where I can set properties of the DatePickerDialog.

I've tried styling it with the code below this, but that doesn't work as the minimum requirement is API Version 21.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyDatePickerDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Is there anyone out there, that have a solution for this problem? My issue only appears in api below 21, as I have a different styling for the api levels above 21.

Regards!

Code for setting up the DatePickerDialog:

```
private void setDateTimeField() {
    Date.setOnClickListener(this);
    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            if(view.isShown())
            {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                String dob_var = dateFormat.format(newDate.getTime());
                String date = dob_var.replaceAll("([A-Z])\\w+ ", "");
                String dayOfWeek = Variables.getDayOfWeek(date);
                Date.setText(dayOfWeek.toUpperCase() + " " + date);

                Variables.dateToGet = date;
                weekNumber.setText(variables.getWeekNumber(date));

                lv.setAdapter(null);
                results.clear();
                new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();
                adapter = new MyCustomBaseAdapter(view.getContext(), results);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

XML File:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/MenuBar</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ShadowMenuBar</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>

    <!--<item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/MyDatePickerDialogTheme</item>-->
</style>


<!--<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>-->
```

Layoutfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="01-01-2016"
    android:hint="Date"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listItemSkema"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:layout_above="@+id/previousDay"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</ListView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/previousDay"
    android:id="@+id/previousDay"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/weekNumber"
    android:text="Uge"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/nextDay"
    android:id="@+id/nextDay"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listItemSkema"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/listItemSkema" />
```

Comment: did you try setting colors pro-grammatically ?

Comment: No I haven't, I'm new to this android kind of deal. But I've literally just now discovered that the same colors appear on a different EditText box, so isnt it possible to set the color globally?

Comment: update your code which is written in the activity file for date picker

Comment: I added it to the above question.

Comment: See the thing you call globally basically is theme. If you talk about color issue in different API, that can be done through code. I am updating the answer. try and let me know.

Comment: I'll stay put for your answer.

Comment: @pratz9999 found any solutions?

Comment: can you post your xml file ? I have tried one change but need to view your xml first.

Comment: @pratz9999 I've added it above, this is the XML file for below version 21.

Comment: you added the resource file. I want you to add layout file. Which is inside the layout folder.

Comment: I've added the layout file now, it doesn't seem to paste it all, the rest is here: http://pastebin.com/XAtHVnGs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100653/discussion-between-pratz9999-and-boog1etv).